# Compare trigger record to aggregate list

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

A few things wrong with this query..

> Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from `List<AggregateResult>` to
>   `List<Recurly_Invoice__c>` at line 3 column 30

and what i really want to do is if (invoice IN firstInvoices)...

hoping for some guidance on how to tackle this. basically i want to query all Recurly_Invoice__c records that have a close date and Status__c = Collected, group them by Account__c, and then keep the oldest one. then if the record that caused this trigger to fire is in that list i want to  change the First_Invoice_del__c field to true.

Here's what i'm working with so far:

```
trigger FirstInvoiceBefore on Recurly_Invoice__c (before insert, before update) {       
    list<Recurly_Invoice__c> firstInvoices = [SELECT MIN(Closed_At__c) FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
                                              WHERE Closed_At__c != NULL
                                              AND Status__c = 'Collected'
                                              GROUP BY Account__c];     
    for (Recurly_Invoice__c invoice : Trigger.new) {
        if (invoice = firstInvoices) {
            invoice.First_Invoice_del__c = true;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a `GROUP BY` clause, your query returns `List<AggregateResult>` instead of `List<MyObject__c>`. There are solution gaps, but to get your code up and running, here's what you want:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new) accountIds.add(record.Account__c);

Map<Id, Datetime> earliestCloseDates = new Map<Id, Datetime>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT Account__c, MIN(Closed_At__c) earliestClose FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
    WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds AND Status__c = 'Collected'
    GROUP BY Account__c
])
    earliestCloseDates.put(
        (Id)aggregate.get('Account__c'),
        (Datetime)aggregate.get('earliestClose')
    );

for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
{
    if (record.Closed_At__c == earliestCloseDates.get(record.Account__c))
        record.First_Invoice_del__c = true;
}
```

---

The way I would implement this requirement is a slightly different approach. First, I would install [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). I would then create a field on `Account` to store the first close date called `First_Invoice_Close__c`. Then I would create the following `Lookup Rollup Summary` record:

- Lookup Rollup Summary Name: `Earliest Invoice Close`
- Parent Object: `Account`
- Relationship Field: `Account__c`
- Child Object: `Recurly_Invoice__c`
- Field To Aggregate: `Closed_At__c`
- Field To Order By: `Closed_At__c`
- Aggregate Operation: `First`
- Aggregate Result Field: `First_Invoice_Close__c`

Once you activate it, you can run a calculate job against your org to backfill the data. It will write the trigger for you. Then you just need the following formula field as your checkbox instead:

```
Closed_At__c == Account__r.First_Invoice_Close__c
```

Comment: @fan Glad I could help. :)